# Angular 4.3 - Http 401 status - Router.Navigate(['/login'] does not navigate

Tags: angular, router

Using Angular 4.3.

I am stuck with a very strange issue related to 401 error and router.Navigate. I am handling exceptions in catch and checking the error status. If status is 401 then navigate to login page. At this state router.navigate does not work, It is not working only when status is 401 [no error on console]. If status is 404 then this.router.navigate (routes to not found component] works fine. Here is my code -

```
protected get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return this.http.get(url, options)      
                   .catch((response) => {

                      if (response.status === 401) {
                          console.log('401 error - navigating');
                          this.router.navigate(['/login']);  
                          return Observable.of(response);                                
                      }
                      return Observable.throw(response);
                   });
```

};

if error code is 404 then router.Navigate works without any issue. See below code [In this code router.navigate works fine and navigates to notfound page] -

```
protected get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return this.http.get(url, options)      
                       .catch((response) => {

                          if (response.status === 404) {
                              console.log('404 error - navigating');
                              this.router.navigate(['/notfoundpage']);  
                              return Observable.of(response);                                
                          }
                          return Observable.throw(response);
                       });
};
```

Comment: Do you check response.status. Do you sure that it is 401?

Comment: Yes, Console shows the respective log message - '401 error.....'. It prints the console message , i.e. Status is 401

Answer (score 1):

I think better way return Observable of the throw. And then catch it in component and navigate to needed route from the component.

```
protected get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return this.http.get(url, options)      
                   .catch((response) => {

                      if (response.status === 401) {
                          console.log('401 error - navigating');
                          return Observable.throw('Unauthorized');                               
                      }
                      return Observable.throw(response);
                   });
```

and in component

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.yourService.yorMethod()
        .subscribe(resp => {
            your code
        }, (err) => {
            if (err === 'Unauthorized') { this.router.navigate(['/login']); 
        });
}
```

Comment: Handing in component may work but I have written a wrapper on Http which sends the request to server. Handling in component requires to handle each component to take care of 401. I want to centralize that part so i am doing that in http wrapper. It really surprising that 404 works fine but 401.

Comment: Hey @user2216584, did you manage to find the solution for this? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @Lajon Sorry for late response! There was an issue internal to my application which was causing the reported issue. Hope you would have resolved your issue by now.